# Declaring an overloaded function in global namespace as friend of template class

Tags: c++, class, templates, namespaces, friend

My issue is simple.  I am able to declare an overloaded function in the global namespace as a friend of a template class in a nested namespace using fundamental types, however if I change the definition and declaration of the function to return size_t, I get C2510 and C4430 errors. This only occurs with the return type of the function.  size_t in the parameter list does not generate the issue.  I have tried ::size_t, ::std::size_t, and std::size_t as well.  Nothing seems to work. What is going on here and why?

I am using MS Visual Studio 2015

Thanks

UPDATED:  Per comments I have included remaining code TestingApp.cpp. I also included stddef which does not solve the problem. With respect to the specific error messages I received, they are:

```
C2510   'size_t': left of '::' must be a class/struct/union TestingApp   
pointer.h   41  
C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support 
default-int TestingApp  pointer.h   41
```

Line 41 that does NOT generate compilation errors:

```
friend int ::fwrite<DATA_TYPE>(const Pointer<DATA_TYPE>& ptr, size_t count, FILE* stream);
```

Line 41 that DOES generate compilation errors:

```
friend size_t ::fwrite<DATA_TYPE>(const Pointer<DATA_TYPE>& ptr, size_t count, FILE* stream);
```

The following two files compile and run with no problem.  However if I substitute int with size_t for the return type (and ONLY the return type keeping size_t as the second parameter of the function in either case) in the forward declaration, friend declaration, and definition, I get the errors indicated above.

```
/*******Begin Pointer.h******/

#pragma once
#include <cstdio>

namespace FW{
    namespace Memory {
        template <typename DATA_TYPE> class Pointer;
    }
}

template <typename DATA_TYPE> inline
/* int works, size_t does not work */
int 
/* size_t */
fwrite(const 
FW::Memory::Pointer<DATA_TYPE>& ptr, size_t count, FILE* stream);

namespace FW{
    namespace Memory{

        template <typename DATA_TYPE> class Pointer {

 /*Line 41*/ friend 
             /* int works, size_t does not work */
             int 
             /* size_t */
             ::fwrite<DATA_TYPE>(const Pointer<DATA_TYPE>& ptr, size_t count, FILE* stream);

            public:
                /* Omitted for brevity */
            private:
               DATA_TYPE* m_pCurrent;

        };


    }
}

template <typename DATA_TYPE>
/* int works, size_t does not work */
int 
/* size_t */
fwrite<DATA_TYPE>(const FW::Memory::Pointer<DATA_TYPE>& ptr, size_t count, FILE* stream) {
    return fwrite(ptr.m_pCurrent, sizeof(DATA_TYPE), count, stream);
}

/*******End Pointer.h*******/


/*******Begin TestingApp.cpp******/

// TestingApp.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstddef>
#include "..\DB\Pointer.h"

int main()
{
    unsigned long* pData = new unsigned long[100];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        pData[i] = i;
    }
    FW::Memory::Pointer<unsigned long> ptr(pData);
    FILE* pFile = fopen("testFile", "wb");
    if (pFile) {
        fwrite(ptr, 10, pFile);
        fclose(pFile);
    }
    delete[] pData;
    pData = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

/*****End TestingApp.cpp*****/

Comment: Please add the necessary code to make your code a [mcve]. Also, please post the error messages, not the error codes.

Comment: Adding the text of the error messages to the question would make it easier to diagnose.

Comment: You can't just assume `std::size_t` is present, you need to include `cstddef` to get a definition for it. Then you can use `std::size_t`. VTC as a trivial error.

Comment: Im confused.  size_t is defined in stdio, stdlib and several others.  Also, if that were the issue, then it would not work with the int return type, and yet it does.  right?